# Confused On Higher Web Root Access For Secure Login

Tags: php, javascript, security, authentication

Going to try and mess around with forms of secure login now, and the php files that connect to the database are going to be stored above the web root, public_html, so they cannot be publicly accessed.

My first question is that people are saying you cannot invoke this php file with Javascript.

That makes sense because Javascript runs client-side and could expose information, but this leaves me a bit confused on how to invoke this php file securely.

**Should I have another php file below the web root that invokes the content-sensitive one above the web root?**

Would this be achieved with "../../some-folder-above-web-root/some-php-above-web-root.php", and if so isn't that revealing to the location of the php file in the web root? Or doesn't it's location matter since people cannot access it (.. hackers).

**All in all I really just want to know how to communicate to a script above the web root, properly and securely.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. There should be a PHP file below the web root that will access the secured PHP files above the web root. In Zend Framework, there is a single index.php file, called the bootstraper, which does many things including:

- set the error display level
- set the include paths
- define global constants
- read the configuration files
- load the library classes
- get the front controller
- configure the database connection
- determine the route, per RESTful url's, and MVC
- set Exception handling
- call the requested controller

I would highly suggest using an MVC framework, they are industry standard, and have pre-built functionality for many common problems including secure logins. Zend Framework implements Access Control Lists style security, though you can easily role your own. Other notable frameworks are Drupal, Yii, Codeigniter, Symphony, CakePHP, and Joomla.

Other best practices for security are:

- filter all file uploads based on mimetype, NOT file extension or filetype
- filter all POST and GET data, based on the database table column type and length
- sanitize all SQL strings before running them
- change all the default login passwords on your servers, ex: Apache, MySQL, FTP, SSH, SVN, etc.
- learn how to configure php.ini, httpd.conf, etc.
- disable any services, modules, and plugins, not being used in your framework, PHP, Apache, and MySQL
- fuzz your code
- use unit tests
- learn a bit about penetration testing

Comment: I know this was answered a while ago but I would love if you could possibly provide some sources you have found. I've been researching a lot of what you said but it's difficult. Or possibly reiterate on some of what you said?

Comment: Start by learning Zend Framework 2, it uses all of the concepts mentioned above. Good sources to learn ZF2: http://akrabat.com/ and http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can give those files READ ONLY permission for other, something like 754 (all permissions for root, read and execute for group, read only for other) for example, then you can read its contents using for example `file_get_contents` and a absolute path.

A common way to do this is have a config file (with the sensible info inside) outside the public web dir, read it using a absolute path, and then use it as variables.

If you want to EXECUTE a script outside the public web path you have to give EXECUTE permission to 'other' which isn't much secure.

Also regarding your question about javascript, it ins't about security: javascript code won't be executed in the server, where the file with sensible info is, it will be executed on the client browser, so there's nothing to read there.